# Google Places API not showing latest reviews

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using google places api to get google reviews. I know that google limits it to 5 or 6 but I would have thought it would show the latest 5/6. But it isnt really showing the new reviews. The format I am requesting the json file is as follows:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=API-KEY&placeid=ChIJqRTobkcMdkgRuCUbYZAvhKI
```

Is there some sort of sort order to add in the querystring?

Answer (score 0):

There's this [googlecode ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4258) with the same query but unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any updates for it.